# How to create a context menu items that creates a file

Tags: registry, windows-explorer

Currently, I have a context menu item to create a PHP file. That is an easy way to prevent me from making them every time again.

It is already listed in the context menu
[image: PHP in menu]

But, unfortunately it does not create a PHP file, it opens command prompt without a command.

This is the command that it needs to execute[image: Register]

Final question: How can I add one .php file when I click on "PHP"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative way with New submenu:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.php]
@="phpfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.php\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phpfile]
@="PHP file"
```

[image]

Comment: What type of records do I need to use?

Comment: @KoenHollander Sorry, don`t understand the question.